# How to revert to the old git merge editor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

VS Code has changed their "merge conflict" interface over the past weeks to a 3 way editor and I can't find a way to revert to the previous editor.

Any suggestions how to revert to the old merge editor including the raw >>>>> type encoding of conflicts?

(edit)
This might work but remains to be tested: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157610 - i.e. add this to settings.json:

`"git.mergeEditor": false`

Comment: Adding `"git.mergeEditor": false` to settings.json worked!